# limit of $\ln(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2})$ as $x $and $y$ tends $0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I tried to find this limit using polar representation $x=r \cos\theta $ and $y=r \sin \theta$
i got something like $\ln (\frac{1}{\cos2 \theta})$ which makes me feel im in wrong way !

is my approach correct ?? and why alpha wolfram said its not exists if so

Comment: Your approch is correct and allow you to conclude that the limit doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

Before calculating you should get some intuition about how the function behaves in the neighbourhood of 0 and whether the limit will depend on the trajectory you choose to converge to zero.
What will be the limit of $(x_n, y_n)$ where $x_n = 0$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{n}$?
What is the limit if $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, but $y_n = \frac{1}{2n}$?
What happens if we try to do $x_n = y_n = \frac{1}{n}$?
This should give you a hint of what's going on

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists, then you have that :

$\underset{x,y\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \ln \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \underset{y\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \ln \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \underset{y\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \ln \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2}$.

But $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = -1$, and $\ln -1$ is not defined, so the limit does not exist.